# Can I specify the result fields in elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my dataset, a document contains 20+ fields with nested objects. Most of them are long text fields. These fields are important for full-text search but we only need to show the title, short-description and Id in output.

Is it possible to specify the output fields in ElasticSearch for a full text query? (like projection in MongoDB)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`fields`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) property of a search request:

> Allows to selectively load specific fields for each document
>   represented by a search hit. Defaults to load the internal `_source`
>   field.
>
> ```
> {
>     "fields" : ["user", "postDate"],
>     "query" : {
>         "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The fields will automatically load stored fields (store mapping set to
>   yes), or, if not stored, will load the `_source` and extract it from it
>   (allowing to return nested document object).

Comment: how do i add one static value `"user" : "kimchy"` and one dynamic query that can be used to search on rest of the fields `"fields" : ["user", "postDate","address","description"],`

Answer (score 11):

Take care in ElasticSearch 1.0.0.RC1 the fields return values now are always lists,
if need the result to be a long instead of a list of longs (which might be a single value list for you most of the time) you can limit those with _source

```
{"_source" : ["field1", "field2", ...],
     "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```