# Specify fields with Elasticsearch Transport client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to specify the fields ES returns via Transport Client, specifically using BoolQueryBuilder?

With REST API, it seems easy, e.g. [Can I specify the result fields in elasticsearch query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343549/can-i-specify-the-result-fields-in-elasticsearch-query)

But not sure how to do it with Transport Client. Looking at BoolQueryBuilder class, I don't see any definitions for fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java your code should look something like this:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("yourindex")
        .setQuery(boolQuery().must(matchAllQuery(), ...))
        .addFields("field1","field2")
        .get();
```

Comment: Actually, if I add .addFields() call to chain, I'm getting a list of SearchHits back, but they are all null, i.e. getSource() is null. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Because you request explicit fields, you have to get the value using the fields command as well: result.getHits().getHits()[0].fields().get("name")

Comment: Thanks Jettro. There is another method suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476493/retrieving-specific-fields-using-the-elasticsearch-java-api which seems cleaner and seems to work for me. Are there any downsides to using that method?

Comment: No turar, that is à fine Solution.