# Elasticsearch: addFields() results in null SearchHit.getSource()

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This is a follow-up to this question: [Specify fields with Elasticsearch Transport client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713692/specify-fields-with-elasticsearch-transport-client/30714571#30714571)

When I try to limit the number of fields in the result by chaining .addFields("field1", "field2") as below, I get a non-empty SearchResponse.getHits(), but for each hit, .getSource() is null. E.g. I would get 10 results for a given query, but I am unable to get the content of each result. Am I missing something?

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("yourindex")
        .setQuery(boolQuery().must(matchAllQuery(), ...))
        .addFields("field1","field2")
        .get();
```

Removing '.addFields("field1","field2")' line works as expected, returning expected content, but for all fields.

Answer (score 3):

When you request specific fields in elastic search java api you will not recive full json, so cant call getSource. There is some method in result set like getFields or getField in hit (so many times goes since I run to that problem) which will return what you want.

It's very unpredictable. I'm agree

Comment: please add correct code to my answer

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476493/retrieving-specific-fields-using-the-elasticsearch-java-api