# Searching boolean keys within nested object in Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-river

I have `user` object and it has nested object `status` which has few boolean flags. I need to search all the users which has that boolean flag. For example search all users which has `flag1` status set. I am able to search with name and phone values

Data structure:

```
user : {
  name: ABC,
  phone: 1234567890,
  status: {
    flag1: true,
    flag9: true
  }
}
```

Comment: for future posts, post what attempts you have made to do this.  You can do this with linq `var filteredusers = UserTable.Where(x => x.flag1).ToList()`

Comment: also tag you language

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I am more specifically looking for solution using elasticsearch may be during index time.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343549/can-i-specify-the-result-fields-in-elasticsearch-query) question should help so in your case `"term" : { "flag" : true }`