# elasticsearch/elastica limit nested results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

is it possible to limit the results from a nested field ?

I have shop owners and shops and for my search results i want to get only 2 shops and not all elements from a owner.

my setup is foselasticabundle 5.0 + elasticsearch 5.4.3

i have tried it with the following query:

```
$query = new Query();
$query->setParams(
    [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            '_all' => $term,
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'nested' => [
                            'path' => 'shops',
                            'score_mode' => 'max',
                            'inner_hits' => [
                                'size' => 2,
                            ],
                            'query' => [
                                'match_all' => ['boost' => 1.0],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
$found = $this->index->getType('owner')->search($query);
```

the query works, but the size parameter is ignored

type definition:

`types:
    owner:
        properties:
            name: { boost: 10, analyzer: snowball }
            created: { type: date }
            shops:
                type: nested
                properties:
                    name: ~
                    address:
                        type: nested
                        properties:
                            city: ~
                            street: ~
                            zip: ~
        persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: AppBundle\Entity\Owner
            provider: ~
            finder: ~`

and here is is a example document:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "app_dev",
                "_type": "owner",
                "_id": "9",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Demo Name",
                    "created": "2017-06-30T22:46:47+02:00",
                    "shops": [
                        {
                            "name": "Shop 1 ",
                            "address": {
                                "city": "Test",
                                "street": "Teststreet 123",
                                "zip": "1234"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shop 2",
                            "address": {
                                "city": "Test",
                                "street": "Teststreet 123",
                                "zip": "1234"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Shop 3",
                            "address": {
                                "city": "Test",
                                "street": "Teststreet 123",
                                "zip": "1234"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `inner_hits` is not what you think it is, [it is used to explain why a query result is what it is](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-inner-hits.html), it doesn't actually limit the nested documents returned. In ES nested documents, contrary to the name, are simply stored on the parent document in its `_source` field, so to remove children you need to use the `fields` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343595/1561465

Comment: okey, but so far i understand the fields parameter is to specify fields but not to limit the results. 

i want not exlude or specify fields, i want to limit the results in a nested fields.

in my case i want just 2 shops from a owner and not all

Comment: Mostly yes, it limits which fields come back in the results. The default is it returns the `_source` field, and as you've seen that includes nested documents. You can't limit the resulting document except via `fields`, but you are right, that doesn't actually help you. As far as I'm aware there's no way to only get a subset of nested documents. The limitation comes from the fact you can't filter arrays, only indicate if a field should return or not. You can use highlights to determine which nested objects matched, but you'll have to programmatically filter them still.

Comment: okey that's good to know, thank you for the help and the explenation =)

Comment: @siva.k if you post this as an answer i will accept it